# rails retrieving button_to parameter in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I iterate over an array of CartItem class I created and populate a view file.

```
<td><%= button_to "remove", :action => :remove_from_cart, :id => cart_item %></td>
```

I would like to be able to get a CartItem instance from params[:id] in the remove_from_cart.
`param[:id]` returns something like `"#<CartItem:0xb77a3dcc>":String` and i could not figure out how to treat it like a CartItem object.

I know the code above works for objects descending from ActiveRecord::Base, and CartItem does not descend from it. I am guessing that might be the reason.

any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to pass a `CartItem` `id` instead of a `CartItem` object. If we assume `CartItem` class has a method called `id` then following code should work.

```
<%= button_to "remove", :action => :remove_from_cart, :id => cart_item.id %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So, should I assume that it is not possible to pass objects as parameters unless they descend from ActiveRecord::Base ?

Comment: Yes. Code treats the ActiveRecord::Base classes as special classes.